# Export Sqldatabase after Systemcrash from Harddrive

Tags: sql-server, export

my System crashed and i cant run the operating system but i can access the old Harddrive via USB like an USB stick. 
Is there a way to export the old SQLDatabase from the HDD.

Comment: Which Database do you use?

Comment: I used a MSSQL Database